# Preventing script-exiting exceptions when finding JSON values that might not exist?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

How would I prevent KeyError when grabbing a value from an API query JSON?

**Explanation**: I am calling an API for a user one at a time. Each user returns a JSON with a set of information. I am creating a dictionary from a few specific pieces of information in that JSON. However, sometimes users don't have a specific value (such as Role or Username). How can I write my program so it doesn't throw an exception and end the program when it can't find this value? And instead of throwing an exception it just enters a blank for that specific dictionary value? I have looked into .get but I cannot seem to get it to work with my specific use case.

Code:

```
APResponse = requests.request('POST', APurl, headers=headers, json={'offset': str(AssetPandaCurrentUser), 'limit': '1'})
    APResponseJSON = APResponse.json()

    AssetPandaUserDict = {
        "Username": [APResponseJSON['objects'][0]['data']['field_52']],
        "Role": [APResponseJSON['objects'][0]['data']['field_49']['value']],
        "User Status": [APResponseJSON['objects'][0]['data']['field_6']['value']],
        "Laptop Status": [],
        "Laptop Serial": []
    }
```

So if "Role" is blank or missing in the JSON, it will just set "Role" to a blank instead of throwing a KeyError exception.

I have tried this:

```
"Username": [APResponseJSON.get(['objects'][0]['data']['field_52'])]
```

But I get an error

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [get()](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dict/get.html) method.

For example:

```
"Role": [APResponseJSON.get(['objects'][0].get("data", {}).get("field_49"{}).get("value")]
```

of course if you are sure that `APResponseJSON.get(['objects'][0]` exists.

You can also prepare [pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) model to easily parse your response.

Comment: Hi, this response threw a few parenthesis and comma errors but after cleaning that up I'm met with an "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'" Error.

Comment: '"AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'" Error' - it means that you are trying to use .get() on the string objects. This is dict method.
Can you attach a response schema? or maybe a link to API docs? I will try to improve my answer.